# RDBMS one-one relationship for more efficient look up?

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, relational-database, rdbms

[image]

The top most database is the simplest but to query if an employee is vegetarian given the employee ID, it'd have to deal with the entire employee list.

The bottom two databases allows you to simply check if the employee ID exists in the `Vegetarian` table, which would be much faster if the list of vegetarians is much smaller than the list of employees.

Is this a common/acceptable practice?

In the bottom most database, i also added a foreign key that references the `Vegetarian` table to allow O(1) checking of vegetarian status (key value will be null if not vegetarian) if we already have the employee record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the topmost structure--the single table--with a partial index on isVegetarian=True.  The index will be small, and provide the same benefit as your second structure.

Comment: It seems like this type of partial index is not supported by MySQL, so i'd have to use the bottom solutions for MySQL?